# How does Fichte account for the existence of inter-subjective reality?

Tags: metaphysics, german-philosophy

I have read many entries on Fichte online. There is never any reference to the question of the origin of inter-subjective reality. How do we apparently see the same world?
There does not seem to be any reference to the question as to how we see any world at all.

I get the impression that he doesn't deal with these questions at all.

Am I right?

Comment: The subjectivist interpretation of Fichte is not supported by modern scholarship. See, for example, [Wood, Fichte’s Intersubjective I](https://web.stanford.edu/~allenw/webpapers/FichteIntersubjective.pdf):"*Fichte provides a transcendental deduction of the concept of the other I, as a condition for experiencing the individuality of our own I*"; or [Clarke, Fichte's theory of Intersubjectivity](http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/3659/), where Fichte is a "*philosopher whose primary concern is with relations between subjects... intersubjectivity is a condition of the possibility of self- consciousness.*"